# Advice with finding and contacting participants for studying crime (interview-based research with ex-offenders)

Tags: research-process, ethics, social-science, qualitative-research

I'd like to conduct a study on street gangs in the 1960s-1980s as part of my PG dissertation. Ideally, I'd like to conduct this as an interview-based study (like an oral history/criminology project) rather than desk/archival research. As such, I'd be looking to interview former members of street gangs about their experiences with gang activities and possibly with criminal justice interventions (e.g. experiences with the police, courts and/or prison).

I was wondering whether anyone has any guidance or advice on how to identify and contact potential participants for studies of crime (or human participant studies more broadly!). My initial thought was to start by establishing contact through online forums with alleged former members and then to use a snowball sampling method for identifying other participants, but I also wondered about establishing contact through prisons/rehabilitation services/charities for ex-offenders (although I'm unsure if this is appropriate conduct). I have asked my supervisor but unfortunately this is not the sort of study they have conducted before and they are therefore unable to advise.

Comment: This is an excellent question for your advisor. Doing this right is very important. You can do serious harm to people if you get it wrong. You could also easily end up breaking (privacy) laws or ethical standards. This is a minefield you should not enter alone, and random people on the internet are not the companions you need here.

Comment: Branching out in new directions is a good idea. However, if your advisor is unable to assist you in this very important area, then there is a major issue here. Ideally, try reaching out to other potential collaborators with expertise (can your advisor put you in touch?). If that is not possible, or the collaborators are not interested, then your best bet might be to shift your research direction. Better to do that now rather than three years down the road when an expert looks at your papers and finds flaws that are obvious to the expert you did not find *now*.

Comment: What is PG? ...

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Probably "postgraduate".

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering whether anyone has any guidance or advice on how to identify and contact potential participants for studies of crime (or human participant studies more broadly!)

You need institutional review board (IRB) approval to do anything of this sort. That is your first step. If your advisor is unfamiliar with submitting to an IRB, you need a different supervisor.

The IRB process will guide you through what you need to do to protect their data and identities (although your mileage may vary with IRBs).

Furthermore, under the US Common Rule, [prisoners are treated a special, vulnerable population](https://www.hhs.gov/ohrp/regulations-and-policy/guidance/faq/prisoner-research/index.html), due to a [history of exploitative research on them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimentation_on_prisoners). You seem to indicate you want to primarily interview people who are not currently in jail (given the crimes would have been 40+ years ago), but if you want to be able to talk to anyone *who is* in jail, you need specific permission.

I doubt a prison specifically would enable you to reach former incarcerated people, you would probably have a better bet scouring court records (but I have no specific expertise).